# Setting memoir's \pagestyle within an environemnt

Tags: header-footer, environments, memoir

I am defining an environment with `\newenvironment`, and inside this environment, I want to change the memoir page style. For instance, I want to do `\begin{myenvironment}` and inside this environment, the page style should be `mystyle`.

However, if I add `\pagestyle{mystyle}` to `myenvironment`'s definition, this doesn't work. Strangely, `\thispagestyle{mystyle}` does, albeit of course for one page.
It also works when I call `\pagestyle{mystyle}` every time before `\begin{myenvironment}`, but this is exactly what I want to avoid.

**How can I set the page style from within an environment?**

Comment: `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle` have different functions.  `\pagestyle` sets the style globally -- but very often, the first page of some segment (e.g. `\chapter`) sets a particular page style that overrules the global setting.  that's when `\thispagestyle` comes into play -- to reset the style of the current page.  so it sounds like you want (and need) *both*.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I assume I only need `\pagestyle`, as I want to change the style for a number of pages and not just for the page in which the environment is called. So actually: setting the page style when the environment opens, and resetting it when it closes.

Comment: no, you've misunderstood.  every page starts with an assigned style.  if anything is set on that page, the style is "frozen", and you need to use `\thispagestyle` to change it.  that's what's happening when you set `\pagestyle` *within* an environment -- it won't change until the next page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ah yes, indeed, I forgot to mention that I start a new page in the environment (see David's answer below).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your comment seems in contrast with this observation: IIUC, the last page uses the style active when the page ends—so one needs `\clearpage` in scope of the desired `\pagestyle`. Is the page style frozen at the start or at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page styles apply to pages and they are a physical unit that does not respect environment boundaries. the answer to your question depends what you want to happen if an environment starts half way down page 2 carries on through page 3 and 4 and ends half way down page 5. 
which page styles do pages 2 and 5 get?

The simplest answer if you synchronise page breaking and environment scope in this case so

```
\newenvironment{myenv}
{\clearpage\pagestyle{foo}....}
{...\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}}
```

ensures that the scope of your environment consists of whole pages, each with the specified page style, (reverting?) to plain style at the end.

Comment: `\clearpage\pagestyle` is precisely what I want and currently have in my environment definition, yet it doesn't work. The page style doesn't change, only when I call it manually from outside an environment / environment definition.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh In that case the usual comment applies: please _always_ provide a complete small example document that shows the problem.

Comment: Turns out that this works great, if only you write `\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}` at the end of the environment.